# How to prevent swf to create its own session id?

Tags: session, cookies, flash, session-cookies

I have a swf which is embedded in an html file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <title>v2</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        <!--#wrapper { width:100%; height:100%;}
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; text-align:center;}-->

        </style>
    <script language="javascript">AC_FL_RunContent = 0;
        </script>
    <script src="/AC_RunActiveContent.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        function backfunc(arg){
            window.location.replace(arg);
        }   
    </script>
<head>
<body>

    <script language="javascript">
    var flashpath = '{{song.flashURL}}' + '?date=' + new Date().getTime();
    var songId = {{song.id}};
    var vars = 'username={{current_user.first_name}} {{current_user.last_name}}' + '&' +
               'songid={{song.id}}' + '&' +
               'sessionid={{session_id}}';
    if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
        alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
    } else { 

        AC_FL_RunContent(
            'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=11,0,0,0',
            'width', '640',
            'height', '480',
            'src', flashpath,
            'quality', 'high',
            'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
            'align', 'middle',
            'play', 'true',
            'loop', 'false',
            'scale', 'default',
            'wmode', 'window',
            'flashVars',vars,
            'devicefont', 'false',
            'id', '{{song.flashURL}}',
            'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
            'name', '{{song.flashURL}}',
            'menu', 'true',
            'allowFullScreen', 'true',
            'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
            'movie', flashpath,
            'salign', ''
            ); //end AC code
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a button in my swf which calls a javascript function to redirect the page to homepage. AS3 and js codes are the followings:
AS3:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available){
    txt.text = url;
    ExternalInterface.call("backfunc",url);
}
else{
    txt.text = "ex int not available"; 
}
```

js:

```
function backfunc(arg){
    window.location.replace(arg);
}
```

When I do this operation, the problem occurs. The problem is that when the homepage is loaded I see the old logged out user's page since flash keeps the old and dead session id. Hence, I could not manage the session between only the browser and server because of the swf. How can I fix this problem. I have been searching in google and here for 2 weeks and lastly I have decided to write here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think Flash knows anything about the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem at last. The problem is the domain. When a user enter the site from www.site.com, browser creates a session. In our server codes, redirections were made as site.com/blabla. Since "www" is missing, browser creates a new session and here comes the problem. I have solved the problem by using relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Definetly the problem is not flash related. Session is server side and i couldnt see any server script in your page. (Like PHP or C#)